# SQL:Last date of Join table

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Table:

msub ->id,receive

msublist ->id,sub_id,item_id,qty

i'm try.

```
select a.sub_id
, a.item_id
, a.qty
, b.id
, b.receive_date
from msublist a 
 join (select x.id
, x.receive_date
from msub x
where x.receive_date = (select max(x1.receive_date)
                       from msub x1
                       where x1.id = x.id)) b
on (a.sub_id = b.id)
order by a.item_id,b.receive_date desc
```

it'not work.I want to be show lastdate of item_id

Comment: Looks like the x.id isn't defined in your second sub query for max date. What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql

Comment: I want to show the last withdrawal of every item.I using mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT msublist.sub_id AS msub_id,
       msublist.item_id AS item_id,
       msublist.qty AS qty,
       msublist.id AS msublist_id,
       mostRecentDate AS receive_date
FROM msub
JOIN msublist ON msub.id = msublist.sub_id
JOIN ( SELECT item_id,
              MAX( receive_date ) AS mostRecentDate
       FROM msub
       JOIN msublist ON msub.id = msublist.sub_id
       GROUP BY item_id
     ) AS mostRecentDateFinder ON msublist.item_id = mostRecentDateFinder.item_id
                              AND msub.receive_date = mostRecentDateFinder.mostRecentDate
ORDER BY item_id;
```

This statement starts with a subquery that performs an `INNER JOIN` between `msub` and `msublist`, then groups the results by `item_id`.  Then for each group (i.e. for each `item_id` value) it finds the maximum value of the corresponding `receive_date` values.

The resulting list then has an `INNER JOIN` performed between it and the dataset that results from joining `msub` and `msublist` on their common value in such a way that only those rows from the `msub` / `msublist` dataset that have a matching combination of `item_id` and `mostRecentDate` are retained.

The resulting dataset is then sorted by the value of `item_id`.

Finally, the desired fields are then returned.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Answer modified and explanation added.  You're welcome - I'm glad to help.  Please note that if an Answer does indeed answer your question, and if it is the most suitable Answer available, then you may accept it by clicking on the tick next to the top of the Answer.  This gives the Answerer a small reward of 15 points and removes your question from StackOverflow's list of unanswered Questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
select a.sub_id
, a.item_id
, a.qty
, b.id
, b.receive_date
from msublist a 
inner join
(
 Select a.sub_id,b.id,a.item_id, max(b.receive_dt) as receive_date
 from
 msublist a
 inner join
 msub b
 on a.sub_id=b.id
 group by a.sub_id,b.id,a.item_id
) b
on a.sub_id=b.sub_id and a.item_id=b.item_id
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

Try this

---

```
   select   a.sub_id
        , a.item_id
        , a.qty
        , b.id
        , b.receive_date
   from msublist a 
   join (select x.id
        , x.receive_date
        from msub x
        where x.receive_date = (select max(x1.receive_date)
                               from msub x1
                               )) b
    on a.sub_id = b.id
    order by a.item_id,b.receive_date desc
```

---

Is this is the one you are looking for??

Comment: It only shows items with the latest draw. But I want to show the last withdrawal of every item.

Comment: can you pls bit clear with any sample data if possible?